# How to display text and images in a grid or block format?

Tags: html, css, formatting

I have several images and text that I'd like to arrange in a specific format but, despite trying `display: inline-block` and floating them, I can't quite achieve the effect I need. Margins are helping, but they're not quite doing it.

I'd like an image, then some text beside it, then below, text first, then image beside that text. How can I achieve the layout shown in the image below?

```css
h4 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class= "container">
    <h4>
        <center>
            <img src="Jeff Crowd.jpg" alt="Customer Service">
            <p>With a wide selection of batteries and generators, protective and decorative riding gear, helmets and accessories to fit any make and model, Great Plains is your local stop for all antique and modern motorcycle needs.</p>
            <p>With a dedicated service department comprising over 50 years experience with all makes and models, Great Plains Cycle can accomdodate any service request with efficiency and professional expertise. For any service requests, please contact us at info@example.com or stop in to speak to a professional.</p>
            <img src="Tool Box Resize.jpg"alt="Tool Box">
        </center>
    </h4>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Well, clearly that was helpful. My image didn't even show up. Sorry everybody.

Comment: http://imgur.com/kWTVqNv

Comment: You want image one with text on the right, and image two with text on the left side?  With image one physically above image two?

Comment: Yes, sir. Well, technically I'd like text above the bottom image, such as that imgur link that I posted. I figured that once I understand how to do that, it can't be hard to just replace text/image with one another to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Without testing, I would think NiMa should have you where you want.  Worst case scenario (WORST) you could use a table.  But that's not really a best practice for page layout.

Answer (score 0):

as I understand you should use `float` for your image like :

```
#container img
{
    float: left;
}
```

have a look at http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/WD/wds4p6.html please

Edit :

```
<div class= "container">
    <h4>
        <center>
            <img id="img1" src="Jeff Crowd.jpg" alt="Customer Service">
            <p>With a wide selection of batteries and generators, protective and decorative riding gear, helmets and accessories to fit any make and model, Great Plains is your local stop for all antique and modern motorcycle needs.</p>
            <p>With a dedicated service department comprising over 50 years experience with all makes and models, Great Plains Cycle can accomdodate any service request with efficiency and professional expertise. For any service requests, please contact us at info@greatplainscycle.com or stop in to speak to a professional.</p>
            <img id="img2" src="Tool Box Resize.jpg"alt="Tool Box">
        </center>
    </h4>
</div>
```

and CSS :

```
#img1
{
   float : left;
}

#img2
{
   float : right;
}
```